Excel formula: find if ANY word in a multi-worded cell matches ANY word in a list of words in a column
See the screenshot below.  I'd like a formula that tells me if any words in an A cell (say, A2) matches ANY of the words in the entire Column B (printing, vintage, etc.).  Most, if not all, of the Column A cells will have multiple words while Column B cells contain only single words.  But again, I do NOT want to know if you can find Column B words in Column A cells but rather if each individual A cell contains words that match ANY of the Column B words (from B2 to B1000 if I have to).
The red Yeses and Noes are what I want.  I did this manually, but I'd like a formula.  So the formula will run all of, say, cell A2's words ("vintage" and "shirts") through the entire Column B's words, put a Yes or No in Cell C2 if any word matches, then go onto the next A cell (A3, A4).  Obviously, I can just copy and drag the formula from C2, but I'd need such a formula first.
What I want is in red

What can I try next? I'm using Microsoft Excel 2010.

=IF(SUM(N(ISNUMBER(FIND(B$2:B$12,A2)))),"Yes","No") entered as an array formula will implement your logic, but will not yield a No for row 9 since the words wet and contest are contained in column B

In case of with holes is it one or two words?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
